# "Man is condemned to be free"

Tags: meaning-in-context, philosophy

How do I comprehend the meaning of "condemned" here?  As far as I searched on the Internet, I found that *to condemn* something means to disapprove of that thing, so does this line mean that man doesn't have freedom?

Comment: I would guess it is suggesting that freedom has some bad consequences, and Man is forced to accept them.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to English Language & Usage. The previous and following sentences would help. Maybe the author is trying to make you think of something *bad* with freedom. For example, if Bob is free to slander Alice, then is Bob's freedom good? After all, he can't blame his slander on his parents, society, or his upbringing. In a sense, Bob is *condemned* because he has the freedom to do something bad.

Comment: This is somewhat philosophical and may get more informed answers over at [philosophy.se]

Comment: I agree with @Mitch, and you might give Fromm’s ‘Fear of Freedom’ a scan. An Existentialist’s perspective.

Comment: [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/condemn) sense (3) is appropriate here: 'If circumstances condemn you to an unpleasant situation, they make it certain that you will suffer in that way.'

Answer (score 3):

Your quote can be attributed to the philosopher [Jean-Paul Sartre](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jean-Paul_Sartre#Being_and_Nothingness_(1943)). The full quote gives the necessary context:

> Man is condemned to be free; because once thrown into the world, he is responsible for everything he does.

Freedom is condemnation insomuch that freedom implies culpability for one's actions. There are surely deeper interpretations of this quote, though those are more on-topic at [philosophy.SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

As always, the Greeks had a word for it:  *paraprodokian (παραπροσδοκιαν)*

> a figure of speech in which the latter part of a sentence, phrase, or larger discourse is surprising or unexpected in a way that causes the reader or listener to reframe or reinterpret the first part.

It was (and still is) most commonly found in comedy and jokes.  And in the original quotation there is a difference from the above explanation.  What gets reframed is the readers understanding of the word freedom.  The unexpected clash is there to make the reader stop and think:  a kind of literary shock tactic.